# how can I address a nested variable in a loop?

Tags: ansible

actually, I'd like to know how to use the value of a nested variable in a loop. I have a list with nested objects, e.g.:

```yaml
kommunen:
  weimar:
    tld: stadt-weimar.de
    desc: Kommune Weimar
    admins:
      fritzfriemel:
        vorname: Fritz
        name: Friemel
        mail: f.friemel@stadt-weimar.de
      frankfrokel:
        vorname: Frank
        name: Frokel
        mail: f.frokel@stadt-weimar.de
```

In Ansible, I created a task to use the values of the key "vorname".

```yaml
- name: "Account Daten testen"
  tags: testusers
  debug:
    msg={{ item[0] }}
  with_subelements:
    - '{{ kommunen }}'
    - admins
```

Am I mixing up things here?

Comment: `I have a list` <= no, you have a dict and you are using concepts made for lists. See (non exhaustive list of documentation to read): https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#list-variables, https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-a-dictionary, https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists, https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-lists-into-dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

> *Am I mixing up things here?*

As already mentioned in the comments, yes, it seems so. So you may proceed further with the there linked documentation and examples.

The following examples show how you could create a simple list of the first level of your dictionary `kommunen` by using [data manipulation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html) and the [Jinja 2 filter `list`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.list).

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    kommunen:
      weimar:
        tld: stadt-weimar.de
        desc: Kommune Weimar
        admins:
          fritzfriemel:
            vorname: Fritz
            name: Friemel
            mail: f.friemel@stadt-weimar.de
          frankfrokel:
            vorname: Frank
            name: Frokel
            mail: f.frokel@stadt-weimar.de
      erfurt:
        admins:

  tasks:

  - name: "Account Daten testen"
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ kommunen | list }}"

  - name: Show admins
    debug:
      msg: "{{ kommunen[item].admins }}"
    loop: "{{ kommunen | list }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Account Daten testen] **********
ok: [localhost] => (item=erfurt) =>
  msg: erfurt
ok: [localhost] => (item=weimar) =>
  msg: weimar

TASK [Show admins] *******************
ok: [localhost] => (item=erfurt) =>
  msg: ''
ok: [localhost] => (item=weimar) =>
  msg:
    frankfrokel:
      mail: f.frokel@stadt-weimar.de
      name: Frokel
      vorname: Frank
    fritzfriemel:
      mail: f.friemel@stadt-weimar.de
      name: Friemel
      vorname: Fritz
```

**Documentation**

- [Data manipulation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html)

**Further Q&A**

- [How to loop over dictionary in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42167747/)
- [Iterate over dictionary in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68817151/)

---

> *Is it mandatory to transfer the dict into a list, or can I point to an object directly?*

This will depend on what you try to achieve. If you like to iterate over it, yes. If you have already some information from elsewhere you could use

```yaml
  - name: Set CITY
    set_fact:
      CITY: "weimar"

  - name: Show admins
    debug:
      msg: "{{ kommunen[CITY].admins[item].name }}"
    loop: "{{ kommunen[CITY].admins | list }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Set CITY] *************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Show admins] **********************
ok: [localhost] => (item=fritzfriemel) =>
  msg: Friemel
ok: [localhost] => (item=frankfrokel) =>
  msg: Frokel
```

Comment: What I'd like to do is to use elements of a deeper level of the dictionary, e.g. mail, name and vorname. Is it mandatory to transfer the dict into a list, or can I point to an object directly?

Comment: @sebbe, regarding "_Can I point to `name` or `vorname` directly?_", to do so you would need to know how the nodes in the dictionary are named. I've added an example which shows it for the city, but not for `admins[item]`. Maybe an other or simpler data structure can be used as I don't see an advantage why the data set of the admin is named like his content `fritzfriemel` = `$vorname + $name`. It is mixing up data and meta data which it shouldn't.

Comment: thank you, @U88D. Thank you very much for your clarification. In the meantime, the data structure changed a bit. The data comes via csv files. I end up with a variable like this: